# writing a pseudecode about database connection in php and sql

Tags: javascript, php, database

İ have a few topics which has different subtopics. İ want to load this subtopicswhen topics are choosen and i can do it.but the problem is some subtopics has different header while some have same header.how a program can decide which subtopic has which header.

Simple example:
İ must load headers to the page then i should decide which subtopics has which header.

I have tree table in my db

1. Topics and topics-id in table1
2. Headers and headers-id and topic-name in table2
3. Subtopics and subtopics-id and header-name in table3

**edit** my pseudocode is

```
If (subtopicid == headerid){go there}
```

If i can write 1==header id its okay but i need to get subtopic id at the same time from db.thats my real problem.i gues i cant say it more clear than that

Comment: WHat have you tried so far? WHat'S your database structure? How do those subtopics and their headers look like? Provide some more details and code please.

Comment: @JohannesH. I stuck every time while deciding which subtopic will go in which header. I couldnt write a program for it

Comment: you need to link the headers to the topics somehow. As your headers got IDs, just add another column to you topioc table with the ID of the header that should go with it. Then you can either do two queries to get the topic and the header, or do a JOIN in your database to get both (depending on what DBMS you use).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "join" with SQL => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html